# If JSON response is "true", don't show results in Table View

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm getting this JSON:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2013-05-03T22:03:45Z",
    "resultsOffset": 0,
    "status": "success",
    "resultsLimit": 10,
    "breakingNews": [],
    "resultsCount": 341,
    "feed": [{
        "headline": "This is the first headline",
        "lastModified": "2013-05-03T21:33:32Z",
        "premium": false,
        "links": {
            "api": {
```

And use this to load it in a UITableView:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *headlinesArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/now/?leafs=%@&teas=%@&apikey=xxxxx", leafAbbreviation, teaID] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
            loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){

                premiumArray = objects;

                [_tableView reloadData];

            };
            [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[Feed mapping] forKeyPath:@"feed"];
            loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
                //NSLog(@"BodyAsString: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
            };
        }];
     }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Feed *feedLocal = [headlinesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *headlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.headline];
    cell.textLabel.text = headlineText;

    return cell;
}
```

Headline class model:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *headline;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Links *linksHeadline;
```

Is there any way to check if `premium` is `true` in the JSON, to not show the headline in the `UITableView`?

**EDIT 1**
I added `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *premiumArray;` which is pulling in the correct data associated with `premium`, so now I just need help looking thru that array for links that say `TRUE` so my `UITableView` won't show any headlines that premium = TRUE.

**EDIT 2**
I posted the `viewDidLoad` code above.

**EDIT 3**

Feed.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *headline;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *premium;
```

Feed.m

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"headline", @"headline",
         @"premium", @"premium",
         nil];
    }];
    return objectMapping;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
I added this per some answers, but still couldn't get it working, any thoughts?
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *premiumArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutable;

 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/now/?leagues=%@&teams=%@&apikey=5qqpgrsnfy65vjzswgjfkgwy", leagueAbbreviation, teamID] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){

            //sports = objects;
            premiumArray = objects;

            [_tableView reloadData];

        };
        [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[Feed mapping] forKeyPath:@"feed"];
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
            //NSLog(@"BodyAsString: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        };
    }];

self.myMutable = [[premiumArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"premium = YES"]] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create some sort of UITableView data source. Having the UITableView handle this is much more difficult than simply setting up a data structure and then pass that data in to the UITableView data source.

A NSMutableArray would work just fine for what you need done. Whatever JSON parser toolkit you are using, you are likely given an arrayed response, which looks like is stored in headlinesArray, each containing the example code above.

You simply need to enumerate through headlinesArray and IF the [post objectForKey:@"premium"] == TRUE then add it to the NSMutableArray.

Place all of this in the viewDidLoad so that it is processed before the UITableView is built and then in the TableView you simply need to access that newly built array.

```
.h
@interface YourClass: YourClassSuperclass
{
   NSMutableArray *a;
}

.m

//In ViewDidLoad

a = [NSMutableArray array]; //Allocs and Inits a new array.

for (Feed *f in headlinesArray) //For all feeds in the headlines array. (f is the local var)
{
  //check if premium == TRUE. If yes, add to a.
}

//Then in your data source methods you just use the array named 'a'

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Feed *feedLocal = [a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //Replaced headlinesArray with a
    NSString *headlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.headline];
    cell.textLabel.text = headlineText;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yup, I'm using RestKit and my View controller is my dataSource and delegate.  Does that still work well with your answer?

Comment: That would be amazing if you could give me a code snippet.  Appreciate it alot-

Comment: I tried this but it is getting a warning on the NSDictionary line saying "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type Feed".  I know the mapping is set up correctly on my modeling,  any thoughts?

Comment: Sure!  I just posted it in Edit #3.  Hope that helps more

Answer (score 1):

In your table view data source, you will want an `NSMutableArray`. When you get the data, use this:

```
NSArray *someFeedArray = ...;

self.mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in someFeedArray)
{
    BOOL isPremium = [[[(NSArray *)dict[@"feed"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:"premium"] boolValue] isEqualToString:@"true"]; //Assuming stored as string

    if (!isPremium) [self.mutableArray addObject:dict];
}
```

In your `numberOfRowsInSection` method, you should do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.mutableArray.count;
}
```

And you're done.

Comment: I would ho with solution too. The first code snippet could be shorter with self.mutableArray = [someFeedArray filteredArrayWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.premium = YES]];

Comment: @Peteee24 Thanks for the response!  But it gives me a warning saying "Incompatible pointer types assigning `NSMutableArray` from `NSArray`", any thoughts?

Comment: @Undo Thanks for the response, and it makes sense, but didn't work for me.  I got you're "someFeedArray" and just called it "premiumArray", "premiumArray" is grabbing all objects perfectly from the JSON.  But I'm getting 0 key/value pairs for the rest of the code that creates the dictionary.  Have any idea why that would be?

Comment: @Reez See updated post. I can't really tell how the `premium` object is being stored in the JSON, so I have to guess :)

Comment: What code snippet would you like me to post other than the JSON response I posted?  I'd love to help make it clearer for you in any way, because I still can't get it working based on adding the `isEqualToString` you added.  Just let me know and I'd be happy to post it-

Comment: I'm using RestKit object mapping

Comment: @Reez Woooh - I'm getting in *way* over my knees. I don't know *anything* about RestKit. Really **all you need to do** is get an array of all the individual objects that make up a cell, loop through them, and add them to an array if they match a certain condition. Hope it helps!

Comment: Sounds good. Yeah, the concept makes sense to me know, just gotta figure out how to implement it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: self.mutableArray = [[someFeedArray filteredArrayWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.premium = YES]] mutableCopy]. Sorry i forgot the mutableCopy.

Comment: @Peteee24 I added a new edit above based on your recommendation, what do ya think?

Comment: As i see, you map only the feed property of the result with RestKit. So if the objects in loader.onDidLoadObjects is an array of Feed models AND the premium property is type of BOOL the filteredArray should filter the premiumArray for items where premium == YES, IF the premium property is string then use @"premium like \"true\"" as format for NSPredicate.